# Cast to value type 'int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, linq

The Following is my code when i am fetching the value from the GameByGameTypes and Categories but in table called GameByGameTypes have column CategoryId  have NULL value. So i want 0 inplace of NULL

```
  Category objCategory;
                var query = (from gametypebygametype in db.GameByGameTypes.Where( x => x.GameTypeId == gametypeid)
                             join category in db.Categories
                             on gametypebygametype.CategoryId equals category.CategoryId into joined
                             from category in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new 
                             {
                                 category.CategoryId ,
                                 category.CategoryName
                             }
                             ).Distinct();
                List<Category> objlistCategory = new List<Category>();
                foreach (var item_temp in query)
                {
                    objCategory = new Category();
                    objCategory.CategoryId = item_temp.CategoryId;
                    objCategory.CategoryName = item_temp.CategoryName;
                    objlistCategory.Add(objCategory);

                }
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can replace

```
select new 
{
    category.CategoryId,
    category.CategoryName
}
```

with

```
select new 
{
    CategoryId = category.CategoryId ?? 0,
    CategoryName = category.CategoryName ?? "",
}
```

If you use ReSharper - it will 'complain' that `?? 0` part is not needed. Ignore it.

And Linq-code you use is translated to SQL. When you execute it - result is null, but strongly-typed compiler cannot believe in that, and awaits non-nullable value. (this is the process of 'materialization', that fails).
So you just 'hint' compiler, that it could be null.

[Here is related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347266/why-would-this-linq-to-sql-query-break-when-i-do-tolist).

Comment: Thanks for hint about ReSharper it threw me off when trying to solve this.

Comment: Welcome) ReSharper hints should be treated with cautions: it is only hints.

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways to work with this:

1. You can set column in database `not null` and set default to column 0.
2. You can set Category property `int? CategoryId`.
3. You can change your query to use DefaultIfEmpty with default value

   ```
           var query = (from gametypebygametype in db.GameByGameTypes.Where( x => x.GameTypeId == gametypeid)
                        join category in db.Categories
                        on gametypebygametype.CategoryId equals category.CategoryId into joined
                        from category in joined.DefaultIfEmpty( new 
                                                                {
                                                                   CategoryId=0, 
                                                                   Categoryname=""
                                                                })
                        select new ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using GetValueOrDefault

```
Category objCategory;
                        var query = (from gametypebygametype in db.GameByGameTypes.Where( x => x.GameTypeId == gametypeid)
                                     join category in db.Categories
    on new {A = gametypebygametype.categoryID.GetValueOrDefault(0)}
                equals new {A = category.categoryID}
     into joined
                                     from category in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     select new 
                                     {
                                         category.CategoryId ,
                                         category.CategoryName
                                     }
                                     ).Distinct();
                        List<Category> objlistCategory = new List<Category>();
                        foreach (var item_temp in query)
                        {
                            objCategory = new Category();
                            objCategory.CategoryId = item_temp.CategoryId;
                            objCategory.CategoryName = item_temp.CategoryName;
                            objlistCategory.Add(objCategory);

                        }
```